# Kendo Grid update all rows afyer cell edit

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a Kendo Grid with incell edit with the following columns:

NAME       SURNAME        AGE

AGE is an editable field. I'm using a simple editor template with a textbox inside.

When user ends to edit AGE field (when the editor template is closed) I want to update all rows and fill AGE field with the same value of the edited row.

Which is the best approach to do that? I don't know where I need to iterate all roww and update the field. Also I don't kno how to update the field (should I use dataItem.set())

Could you help me and tell en in which grid event I can update all rows after the cell edit ?

I'm using 2016 Kendo version

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [save](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/events/save) event:

> Fired when a data item is saved.

Runnable dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/@GaloisGirl/Ilulexez

```
  save: function(e) {
    e.sender.dataSource.data().forEach(function(x) {
       x.set("age", e.values["age"])
    });
    e.sender.refresh()
  }
```